# Невозможно просмотреть источник данных Visual Studio

Tags: c#, mysql, mysqlconnector

Я работаю в Visual Studio 2017 с [пакетом MySql](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/). Задача заключается в том, что бы подключиться к БД MySql средствами Visual Studio, т.е. используя элемент WindowsForms DataGridView. Во время получения данных с БД получаю сообщение об ошибке. Воспроизводится ошибка так:

1. Создать подключение к БД
2. Создть источник данных из высшеуказанного подключения
3. Drag&drop'нул источник данных на форму WindowsForms
4. Вызвал предварительный просмотр данных

Если кто-то встречался с подобными ошибками, будьте добры, подскажите каким образом от неё избавиться[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: возможно, проблема связана с тем, что Windows и MS Visual Studio установлены на разные локальные диски

Comment: исходя из ошибки, у вас отличаются версии установленного пакета, и того, к которому вы подключаетесь

Comment: Удалите пакет nuget Mysql из проекта, и потом в ссылках добавьте сборку Mysql.Data из системных модулей. Или наоборот, если есть желание использовать оригинальный пакет с сайта оракла. При этом поправьте детективы using.

Comment: @NewView, я это делал. Также я пытался комбинировать разные версии connecter.net + mysql for visual studio [текущая конфигурация](https://cdn1.savepice.ru/uploads/2019/3/19/20de9c29d064833cd199d95b2c5d5ac9-full.png). На данном этапе появилась проблема "You have a useable connection already". Исследуя неиссякаемые просторы гугла, наткнулся на багтрекинговый сайт оракла, где иностранцы вдоль и поперёк нахваливают сапортных инженеров, которые уже как 3 года кроме workaround'а ничего предложить не могут. Якобы проблема была решена в релизе .net connector 6.9.9, но мне это не помогло

Comment: Там по надписям очевидно, что есть 2 разных копии библиотек, видно оно автоматом криво ставится (оракл) - вывод, удалить в ручную с корнями оракловую версию, и использовать родную .NET. создайте чистый проект с тестом для экспериментов, и используйте только родные запчасти от Mysql в .NET

Comment: @NewView, спасибо за совет. Не могли бы ли Вы уточнить, где взять "родные запчасти", так как с коробки VS идет без интерфейса для MySql от слова вообще

Comment: Из коробки это не в VS а в .NET, с версии 4.0 кажется идёт в комплекте, у меня есть по крайней мере, а отдельно я его точно не ставил. Возможно он ставиться в комплекте с EF, как предположение, по крайне мере поддержка Mysql там есть из коробки.

Comment: @NewView, не могли бы ли Вы объяснить что конкретно нужно делать, что бы установить это расширение. Я нашёл следующие материалы https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/ef/core/providers/ , однако я не знаком ни с nuget (через который предлагается скачивание всех драйверов) ни с тем, какие модули поддержки mysql необходимы

Comment: В VS меню Tools - пакеты Нугет, `install-package provider_package_name` после активации в пункте Нугет, там где обычно пишутся ошибки, будет вкладка 'терминал Нугет'. И вы нашли нужную вам ссылку.